# pgfplotstable: How to find a row with a value that is lesser or equal to a certain value

Tags: pgfplotstable

[image]

I have a `pgfplotstable` with some values `X` which are numbered by `No`.
(My `X` values ​​are descending.)

*How do I find the number corresponding to the first `X` value less than or equal to (*for example*) `10`?*

In my case that would be `No` = `40`.

Is there an elegant way with `\pgfplotstablesort` or `/pgfplots/iflessthan/` ?

PS: *It would also be ok for my task to create a "sorted table" in which the rows with X-values ​​greater than '10' are skipped.*

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread[header=true, col sep=comma]{
No, X
31, 12.9032
32, 12.5000
33, 12.1212
34, 11.7647
35, 11.4286
36, 11.1111
37, 10.8108
38, 10.5263
39, 10.2564
40, 10.0000
41, 9.7561
42, 9.5238
43, 9.3023
44, 9.0909
}{\mytable}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]{\mytable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done this way:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\pgfplotstableread[header=true, col sep=comma]{
No, X
31, 12.9032
32, 12.5000
33, 12.1212
34, 11.7647
35, 11.4286
36, 11.1111
37, 10.8108
38, 10.5263
39, 10.2564
40, 10.0000
41, 9.7561
42, 9.5238
43, 9.3023
44, 9.0909
}{\mytable}

\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\mytable}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\LastRowNo{\pgfplotsretval-1}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]{\mytable}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\MyValue}{10.2}

\foreach \row in {0,...,\LastRowNo}{%%
 \pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{X}\of{\mytable}
\pgfmathparse{\pgfplotsretval <= \MyValue ? 1 : 0}% \pgfmathresult % Test
\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1 %
  \pgfmathparse{int(\row-0)}%
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfmathresult}{No}\of{\mytable}%
  \xdef\MyNo{\pgfplotsretval}%
  \breakforeach% better...
\fi}%%

The last value that was lesser or equal {\MyValue} has the No {\MyNo}. 
\end{document}
```